# Justify content start если строка не заполнена

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

При работе с Flexbox наткнулся на такую проблему. Как-то не получается решить его без изобретения нового велосипеда.

Вот сам пример.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 24%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">last element</div>
</div>
```

Вот, в примере, последний элемент с надписью `last element` хочу чтобы был слева, там, где тот же элемент предыдущей строки.

То есть если строка не заполнена, то элементы позиционировать слева.

Может кто-то поможет разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: не сильно понятен вопрос... `хочу что бы был с лева, там где тот же элемент предыдущей строки.` вот этот момент

Comment: В **CSS**, есть такая штука [:empty](http://htmlbook.ru/css/empty), попробуйте что-нибудь придумать на основе неё.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы элементы шли один за другим с одинаковыми промежутками — не обязательно использовать `justify-content: space-between`.

В вашем примере элементы, шириной `24%` расположены по 4 в ряд и равномерно распределены между границами flex-контейнера. Т.е. три отступа между ними — это 4% ширины контейнера.

Дело за малым — добавить отступ справа у всех элементов, кроме каждого четвёртого.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 24%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 calc(4% / 3) 20px 0;
}

.child:nth-child(4n+4) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">last element</div>
</div>
```